# Is there any way to set default port for nx react apps

Tags: nrwl-nx

I create multiple apps using nx monorepo, but when I try to run `nx run-many` to start all apps at once, but I got the error that the port is already taken, which is true.

when I run apps one at a time, I can specify a port, but on `run-many` i can't. so is there any way to set the default port for every app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can set the configuration of your React apps by editing `project.json` file

```json
"serve": {
    "executor": "@nrwl/web:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "buildTarget": "admin:build",
        "hmr": true,
        "port": 3001
    },
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
            "buildTarget": "admin:build:production",
            "hmr": false
        }
    }
}
```

Under every command you want to execute, there is an `options` key which you can add `port`.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include the code (or, in this case, JSON) as text, and then format it using Markdown. Don’t include code as a screenshot.

Comment: To be noted, ports below 1024 will not work by default. 
For example: If you want to run your app at port 80, have to setup port forwarding from port 80 to your default port for nx app.